# Using join or multiple selection for Many to Many relation

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, database-design, sqlalchemy

I have the following two tables:

```
FileData:
    * FileSystemID
    * FilePath
    * Checksum
    * Data

ScanResult:
    * Checksum
    * Result
    * ScanType
```

The `FileData` and the `ScanResult` tables are related through their `Checksum` columns.

They can have Many to Many relationship where the important one is the relation from the `FileData` to the `ScanResults`. (The opposite relation is not important.)

The question is, which design is more efficient for this use case:

1. Having an association table between the two tables (which will have the tables foreign keys) so we could use JOIN using this table.
2. Creating queries using SELECT from both of the tables - `SELECT * FROM FileData, ScanResult WHERE FileData.Checksum = ScanResult.Checksum`

If you have any other suggestion then that would be great!

I'm using SQLAlchemy (in python) when the engine is postgresql.

** EDIT **
Sample from the DB:

```
FileData:
FileSystemID | FilePath     | Checksum                          | Data 
 1           | /user1/a.bin | 5953E1EBB5A153AF93DA61EA433889D0  | ...
 1           | /user1/b.bin | 207402D3E82BF24E7ED4965DC66D426C  | ...
 2           | /user2/h.bin | 5953E1EBB5A153AF93DA61EA433889D0  | ...
 2           | /user2/z.bin | 8D41627E46D5B8556D0D3E30EC15538E  | ...

ScanResult:
Checksum                         | Result | ScanType
5953E1EBB5A153AF93DA61EA433889D0 | 1      | general
5953E1EBB5A153AF93DA61EA433889D0 | 0      | logistic
5953E1EBB5A153AF93DA61EA433889D0 | 1      | anomaly
207402D3E82BF24E7ED4965DC66D426C | 1      | general
207402D3E82BF24E7ED4965DC66D426C | 1      | logistic
8D41627E46D5B8556D0D3E30EC15538E | 0      | general
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a question of efficiency as these approaches do different things. It depends on what you need. Option 1 would presumably be used to resolve the M:N. Option 2 would just live with the consequence. Also, it's important to understand that both options JOIN the tables, Option 2 just uses an older, uglier syntax that's fallen out of favor.

Comment: The goal is to create a system where the only relation that will be used is through the FileData table (as one to many relation even though it's many to many). So if you're saying that it's almost the same thing, then it means that the second option is more efficient because we don't need another table

Comment: @Error_2646 If there's another way to join both of the tables without using the "ugly" syntax, then that could be the answer

Comment: Some sample data from FileData and ScanResult with your desired result would help. Even though it probably makes sense to you, sample data removes all ambiguity. I'm not really following "The only relation that will be used..." Inner joins are commutative, so only caring about one side of the relationship is not a thing. What do you mean by that? If a checksum from ScanResult is not in FileData that record can be omitted?

Comment: @Error_2646 The thing is, the only used queries in the system are: Single Queries for ScanResult, Single Queries for FileData and Relational Queries from FileData (receiving it's ScanResult).. So in theory there could be a situation where there's a ScanResult with a checksum that's not in the FileData (for example, if we would delete the records from the FileData table (probably won't happen)) but the record will be still valid. I will try to add a sample in a minute.

Comment: @Error_2646 Added the sample